# Not able to download an Image using Glide/Picasso/UIL in android

Tags: android-imageview, picasso, universal-image-loader, android-glide

I need to download [this](https://6c73ec32809e24a946f3-aa7af6ebb2a75eb1fcb40ffdd6280525.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/_151223044138_1147101.png) image in my android application. I have tried downloading using Picasso, Glide and UIL. I'm getting the following error every time.

```
"skia: --- decoder->decode returned false".
```

Here is how I have tried using Glide:

```
Glide.with(getActivity()).load(url).into(imageview);
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The image may be broken. I've seen that happen before and I think it was related to some camera models...

Answer (score 0):

The image you are sending is not properly encoded or the tags are incorrect. As you can see what Google Images says:
*

> The image is too large (over 8000 by 6000 pixels), or Google can't
>   read its encoding.

*
Either Android says it's too big and doesn't load it, or loads it and cannot decompose it into a Bitmap to display in the ImageView.

Try using any other random image and you'll see it working.
If that's your own image, try exporting it again in Photoshop or whatever software you were using.

I hope it helps, kind regards!